# What should my JSON response contain when I have an HTTPException?

Tags: json, rest, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I let users register for my application in the following code:

```
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        [System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
        //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        //public HttpResponseMessage Register(RegisterModel model, string returnUrl)
        public UserProfileDto Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (WebSecurity.UserExists(model.UserName))
                {
                   throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Attempt to register the user
                    try
                    {
                        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                        WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);

                        InitiateDatabaseForNewUser(model.UserName);

                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, createPersistentCookie: false);

                        var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
                        responseMessage.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.google.com");

                        return _service.GetUserProfile(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
                    }
                    catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                    {
                        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
```

My question(s): If I hit one of those exceptions, I'd like to tell the user "Hey, that username already exists!" or "Yikes, something happened.  We're looking into it." etc.  Clientside, how should I be handling this?  Just check the status in the header and send something to the view accordingly?

Does this mean that each possible error should use a different status code?  That seems wrong... which leads me to asking - should I be sending some kind of status-related data back to the client?  If so, should my return type (in this case, UserProfileDto) contain a field for "status" that I can populate however I see fit in my controller?

Sorry I asked a bunch there... just trying to figure out how to do this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ReasonPhrase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.reasonphrase.aspx) exists for the purpose of providing a readable description of why an error occurred.  If a simple textual description is not sufficient to convey the problem to the end user then there are some emerging standard ways of describing a problem to your user.

`application/api-problem+json` https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-problem-03
`application/api-problem+xml`

`application/vnd.error+json`  https://github.com/blongden/vnd.error
`application/vnd.error+xml`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a model that allows you to pass either the registration information or an error message back to the client.

The model(s) might look something like:

```
public class RegistrationModel
{
    public UserProfileDto UserProfile { get; set; }
    public ErrorModel Error { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorModel 
{
    public string Message { get; set;}
}
```

Also, you should probably be returning an HttpResponseMessage which allows you to specify your model:

```
return Request.CreateResponse<RegistrationModel>(HttpStatusCode.Created, MyModel);
```

Comment: Thanks Jed.  It seems messy to think that all of my models need an "error" property now... is there an alternative?  Would it be ok to just rely on the HttpStatusCodes to I'm not bloating my models?

Comment: Ultimately what ever works for you is what you should do. I think having an error property on your models allows you to do you quick if(Model.Error!=null) {...} check on the client side and you're able to send along more information about the error with the response. It's not so much bloat as it is flexibility.